# What is the cause of the Sphinx warning "Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent" in a one line docstring

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, myst

When I build my Sphinx HTML documentation, I get a warning.

> checkdmarc.py:docstring of checkdmarc.BIMIRecordInWrongLocation:1: WARNING: Block quote ends without a blank line; unexpected unindent.

`BIMIRecordInWrongLocation` is a simple `Exception` class with a one line docstring.

```py
class BIMIRecordInWrongLocation(BIMIError):
    """Raised when a BIMI record is found at the root of a domain"""
```

Oddly, the warning persisted even after I replaced the docstring with `pass`.

For context, here is the [full code](https://github.com/domainaware/checkdmarc/blob/4fcdd758f90395312a6a030aef7491bd96dc4c09/checkdmarc.py#L296), and the Sphinx [build log](https://github.com/domainaware/checkdmarc/actions/runs/3723676690/jobs/6315337532#step:5:20).

Comment: My guess is the differing indentation levels of the [preceding docstring](https://github.com/domainaware/checkdmarc/blob/4fcdd758f90395312a6a030aef7491bd96dc4c09/checkdmarc.py#L289-L293). If you dedent the indent by one space, it should pass.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, but it was because I had a new line character in the docstring.
I removed it and it worked.